# inteliJ IDEA don't store the project informations

Tags: intellij-idea

Every time I create a new project in InteliJ it creates only a iml file, and I cannot see my file and libraries. But after I close the project and make the same project by override, it works.

[image]

I suspect it's something from the settings, but I don't know where.

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-213.5744.223, built on November 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.13+7-b1751.19 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 7 6.1

PS: I am looking for a more permanent solution, as it gets fustrating..

Comment: When you create a new project there are no files or libraries.  You have to add them.  Your complaint isn't clear to me.

Comment: Please describe the process of creating a project step by step. See if https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that it has a small bug.

[image]

When I make a new project, I have 2 ways of creating in:

1. by choosing a name in the **Project name** field, and then obtional choose the path manually if required. This works very well.
2. by skip the first field and live *untitled* as it is, and choose the path in the **Project location** field, creating a new folder, and then when you came back the **Project name** field is with the name of the folder, but when I click finish, I can not see modules, compiler settings and SDK selected. (see the picture from the question)